# Select top 50 rows from a table, but display oldest to newest?

Tags: php, sql

Can someone advise on how to get around this problem?

I want to call the top 50 rows by id from my SHOUTBOX table, but display them in a div in ascending order (the most recent row (newest) at the bottom)

for example;

most recent row is id 200,
I want to call rows 150 - 200,
display them in the div like;

150,
151,
152,
.
.
.etc
.
.
200 <<< last line in DIV

my PHP code currently looks like this;

```
$recall=mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%H:%i:%s') as timepost FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");

    while($comm=mysql_fetch_object($recall)){
      if ($comm->poster == "System"){
      print"<font color=#3399FF>$comm->timepost-<strong><a href='profile.php?viewuser=$comm->poster' target='iframecontent'><font color=#3399FF>$comm->poster</font></a></strong>: </font>";
    echo replace($comm->post);
    echo"<br>";
      }
```

but it returns my data in the div like;

200,
199,
198,
.
.
.etc
.
.
150 <<< last line in DIV

Please can anyone help?

note: I am currently working through all my pages and converting all mySQL queries to PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, if you're converting to PDO there is the exact answer for reading backwards on this page without changing your query. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php.

For now this will work:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%H:%i:%s') AS timepost FROM (SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50) AS foo ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: No, my doesn't support it either by the looks of it. (its throwing the mysql boolean error.

Im looking into your PDO advice now. Read backwards looks exactly right for what I need. I may aswell just convert this page to PDO now and be done with it.

Comment: `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%H:%i:%s') as timepost FROM (SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50) AS table ORDER BY id ASC` should work.

Comment: no :( not working my end.

line 89 - `$recall=mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%H:%i:%s') as timepost FROM (SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50) AS table ORDER BY id ASC");`

line 92 - `while($comm=mysql_fetch_object($recall)){`

im getting same boolean error on line 92.

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/*****/public_html/*******/shoutbox.php on line 92

Comment: Oh, table is a keyword. My bad, name it foo or something `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%H:%i:%s') AS timepost FROM (SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50) AS foo ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: LEGEND!

Your reputation precedes you!

edit your original answer to reflect the the 'table/foo' comment and ill mark it as accepted :D

Answer (score 1):

replace `ORDER BY id DESC` by `ORDER BY id`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this:

```
$recall=mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%H:%i:%s') as timepost FROM (SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50) ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/*******/public_html/**********/shoutbox.php on line 88

Comment: You may need an alias for the inner select.

Comment: hmmm, cant seem to get this working using any of these methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong the order command, you have to put `ASC` instead of `DESC` Here is your correct query:

```
$recall=mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%H:%i:%s') as timepost FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50");

    while($comm=mysql_fetch_object($recall)){
      if ($comm->poster == "System"){
      print"<font color=#3399FF>$comm->timepost-<strong><a href='profile.php?viewuser=$comm->poster' target='iframecontent'><font color=#3399FF>$comm->poster</font></a></strong>: </font>";
    echo replace($comm->post);
    echo"<br>";
      }
```

Comment: I have more than 50 rows in the table though. 
I have tried this and it doesn't return the most recent 50 rows.
:\

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
$recall = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%H:%i:%s') as timepost 
   FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50");
```

Comment: If you just change DESC to ASC it will start always from 0-50, he is looking for 150-200